# Prevent user to type more than one decimal dot in a JS calculator

Tags: javascript, arrays, decimal, calculator

In my calculator project with Javascript I'm trying to prevent a user to input multiple decimal points if there is one already (example : 5.2.3.56 not allowed).

All the numbers, decimal and operator buttons that the user clicks on are pushed and stored in an array.

How can I check if there is a dot already and disable the button using an array of values?

```
const numButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.number');

const opButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.operation');

const display = document.querySelector('.display');

const decimal = document.querySelector('.decimal');

let opClicked;

let resultArray = [];

// Event listeners

numButtons.forEach(number => {
    number.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    numClicked = e.target.textContent;
    
    if (display.textContent === '0') {
        display.textContent = '';

    } else if (resultArray[resultArray.length - 1] === opClicked){   
        display.textContent = '';
    }
    resultArray.push(numClicked);
    display.textContent += numClicked
});

opButtons.forEach(operator => {
    operator.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    empty();

    opClicked = e.target.textContent;
    resultArray.push(opClicked);

    operate();
 
});

decimal.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    let decimalClicked  = e.target.textContent;

    resultArray.push(decimalClicked);
    display.textContent += decimalClicked;
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var decimalClicked  = e.target.textContent;
    
    if(resultArray.includes(decimalClicked) == false){
        resultArray.push(decimalClicked);
        display.textContent += decimalClicked;
    }
});
```

The code above checks the resultArray to see if it contains a decimal, if it does not, then it appends the decimal to the array